# Custom HTML Helper to add Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, html-helper

I set up a Kendo Window HTML Helper to display a message based on a user action. It just fads in to display the message and then fades out. Since this helper is going to be used on every page and never changes, I decided to wrap it in a custom HTML Helper. It looks like this:

```
        public static Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WindowBuilder CustomWindow(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        var animationOpen = new Action<PopupAnimationBuilder>(x => x.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In).Zoom(ZoomDirection.In).Duration(700).Expand(ExpandDirection.Vertical)));
        var animationClose = new Action<PopupAnimationBuilder>(x => x.Close(close => close.Fade(FadeDirection.Out).Zoom(ZoomDirection.Out).Duration(700).Expand(ExpandDirection.Vertical)));
        var window = helper.Kendo().Window().Name("window").Animation(animationOpen).Animation(animationClose).Width(500).Visible(false).Title("Notice");
        return window;
    }
```

This works perfectly but I also have a javascript function I would like to become a method on the window object itself. The function looks like this:

```
            function showMessage(message, title) {

            if (title === null) title = "Notice";
            var window = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
            window.content("<div style='text-align: center;'><p>" + message + "</p></div>");
            window.showWindow();
            window.title(title);
            window.open();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.close();
            }, 1400);
        }
```

Is there a way I can emit this from my custom helper and ideally attach it do the window object so I can do something like this:

```
var window = $("#window").data("kendoWindow");
window.showMessage('Hello');
```

Thank you for your help

Earl

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your question well and clear, but with what i understood i guess you're trying to add a function as a property to an object. If that is what you need then you can follow this

`window.showMessage =  function (message, title) {
// function statements goes here
 }`

Now the showMessage function will be available in the window object so you can access like

```
window.showMessage("This is my message", "Message title");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to add a custom method to a Kendo UI widget:

- [Create a custom Kendo UI widget](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/create-custom-kendo-widget) that inherits from (extends) the Kendo UI Window. Define the desired custom methods. However, this approach cannot be used with the Window's MVC wrapper.
- Override the client-side Kendo UI Window's prototype. This should happen before any Window instances are initialized.

  ```
  kendo.ui.Window.prototype.showMessage = function(message, title) {
      this.content("My message");
      this.title("My Title");
      this.center().open();

      var thisObj = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
          thisObj.close();
      }, 1400);
  }
  ```